# Conversion from string "a" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, console-application

This one's really got me confused. I'm trying to do a visual basic console application that if the user enters 'A' or 'a' then the program should do 'x', but that's not working. The error I get is:

**Conversion from string "a" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.**

Here's my code:

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Selection As String

    Console.WriteLine("Please select your function:")
    Console.WriteLine("* To convert binary to decimal, press A,")
    Console.WriteLine("* Or to convert decimal to binary, press B")

    Selection = Console.ReadLine

    If Selection = "A" Or "a" Then
        Console.WriteLine("This will be A")
    ElseIf Selection = "B" Or "b" Then
        Console.WriteLine("This will be B")
    ElseIf Selection = Not "A" Or "a" Or "B" Or "b" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Please try again")
        Do Until Selection = "A" Or "a" Or "B" Or "b"
        Loop
    End If


End Sub
```

What should be the correct usage of the Or in this piece of code to make it function correctly?

Comment: You should also provide the user with an escape route, like "Enter Q to quit."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `If` clauses should be like:

```
If Selection = "A" Or Selection = "a" Then
```

The clauses between the `Or` should *each* be boolean expressions, and `"a"` is simply a character, not a boolean expression.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer - that has really helped. I will mark is as the answer when SO allows me to. One other thing, does this apply with the Not statement? Just when I do: "        ElseIf Selection = Not "A" Or Selection = Not "a" Or Selection = Not "B" Or Selection = Not "b" Then" , I get the same error.

Comment: * Conversion from string "f" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: @JakeElsley - The syntax would be: `ElseIf Not Selection = "A" Or Not Selection = "a" Or Not Selection = "B" Or Not Selection = "b" Then` but you really need to think about what that means... You should probably be using `AND NOT` instead of `OR NOT`.

Comment: It should be or not Selection = "B". The not has to be before the variable. I agree with Oded that you have to think about what that means. You may want it to be AND instead of OR

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses to this. I can confirm that Oded's code works wonders.

Comment: I know this is off the topic of above, but is there a way to mimic the user pressing the return key, so once a key is pressed, for example A, the console takes the input and processes it accordingly without the user having to press the return key?

Comment: @JakeElsley - Nothing comes to mind, not with a console application. The enter key is what tells the program that input has been inserted. You may want to look at having a windowing interface using some sort of .NET [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library.

Comment: @Oded Okay, no worries. Unfortunately vb consoles are all I am allowed to do for Computer Science, but thank you the link and information.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest changing the string entered into upper case before the if statements. Also the last else if statement isn't needed and can be replaced with a single else.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Selection As String

    Console.WriteLine("Please select your function:")
    Console.WriteLine("* To convert binary to decimal, press A,")
    Console.WriteLine("* Or to convert decimal to binary, press B")

    Selection = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper() 'Not tested otherwise use the one below
'Selection=Selection.ToUpper()

    If Selection = "A" Then
        Console.WriteLine("This will be A")
    ElseIf Selection = "B"  Then
        Console.WriteLine("This will be B")
    Else
        Do Until Selection = "A"  Or Selection = "B" 
               'Loop Code goes here
        Loop
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: That sounds like another pretty good way to resolve the user's input, thank you. That also reduces the code.

Answer (score 3):

Using **Select Case** is yet another alternative:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Please select your function:")
    Console.WriteLine("* To convert binary to decimal, press A,")
    Console.WriteLine("* Or to convert decimal to binary, press B")
    Console.WriteLine("* To Quit, press Q")
    Dim Selection As String = ValidateInput()
    If Selection <> "Q" Then
        'do something
    End If
End Sub

Function ValidateInput() As String

    Dim Selection As String
    Selection = Console.ReadLine

    Select Case Selection.ToUpper
        Case "A"
            Console.WriteLine("This will be A")
        Case "B"
            Console.WriteLine("This will be B")
        Case "Q"
            Return "Q"
        Case Else
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again")
            ValidateInput()
    End Select
    Return Selection

End Function
```

Comment: Wow thank you - I'm getting taught more on here than my teacher has taught me! Thank you! Using a function is another way of doing it, that in theory would make my code more structured, instead of having a big clump of code if that makes sence.

Comment: `Select case` is a much-much better alternative. I was going to post one myself before seeing this answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments Jake and Neolisk. Glad to be of some help.